# Specific crawlable-cleanURL AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I saw a tutorial in this link:
https://moz.com/blog/create-crawlable-link-friendly-ajax-websites-using-pushstate

But I'm about to lose my mind. The author made a impossible thing. He used this code, looking in his example (http://html5.gingerhost.com) source code:

```
<script>
// THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC HAPPENS
    $(function() {
        $('nav a').click(function(e) {
            $("#loading").show();
            href = $(this).attr("href");

            loadContent(href);

            // HISTORY.PUSHSTATE
            history.pushState('', 'New URL: '+href, href);
            e.preventDefault();


        });

        // THIS EVENT MAKES SURE THAT THE BACK/FORWARD BUTTONS WORK AS WELL
        window.onpopstate = function(event) {
            $("#loading").show();
            console.log("pathname: "+location.pathname);
            loadContent(location.pathname);
        };

    });

    function loadContent(url){
        // USES JQUERY TO LOAD THE CONTENT
        $.getJSON("content.php", {cid: url, format: 'json'}, function(json) {
                // THIS LOOP PUTS ALL THE CONTENT INTO THE RIGHT PLACES
                $.each(json, function(key, value){
                    $(key).html(value);
                });
                $("#loading").hide();
            });

        // THESE TWO LINES JUST MAKE SURE THAT THE NAV BAR REFLECTS THE CURRENT URL
        $('li').removeClass('current');
        $('a[href="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass('current');

    }

</script>
```

But I don't know what the hell he wrote on that `content.php` file. It is a perfect AJAX website:

- It works with back button (and keeps using AJAX!);
- It works accessing the direct links to each page on the website;
- And of couse, it works with javascript disabled...

How... I... do that ;-;

I'm still learning AJAX...

Comment: Be more specific, provide your snippets.

Comment: Sojtin, I just want to understand his code. I wanted someone to explain what he put on `content.php`file because there is where the other part of the magic happens. Like, if he simulate the real link of the pages, what the hell content file is doing, you know?